# Wear OS and AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I know that recomended way to show dialogs on wear is using AlertDialog (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/) but by default AlertDialog does not look good on round screens. I know I have to provide custom layout (see [Showing Android Wear style AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945471/showing-android-wear-style-alertdialog)), but then I have to use custom colors and images (i.e. drawable/ic_tick).

Is there a default dialog layout for wear or maybe a better way to use AlertDialog on Wear OS?